# Generating id's of desired length in DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working with Amazon DynamoDB and I need an object to have an id of length 10. I think is not possible to tell Dynamo to auto-generate id's of this length (if I'm wrong, how can I do this?) so I was thinking about setting a field of the object with a unique string of length 10 defined by me. What is the best way to do this? Is auto increment a bad idea for this purpose?

Comment: You are correct that DynamoDB has no way of auto-generating IDs for you. Your code would have to do that. What have you tried so far and in what languages?

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB does not have any mechanism for generating unique ids for new items. However, you hardly need such a feature, because your application can easily generate a 10-byte random string and use that as the key for the new item.

If you're worried that once in a hundred years, this random key will collide with the key of an item that already exists, that's easy to solve too: You can use a `ConditionExpression` in `PutItem` to ask to only create the item if it doesn't already exist:

1. The condition can be that `id <> :id`, where `id` is the key column and `:id` is the random id we're trying to create. This will fail if the item exists (the value isn't not-equal itself), but will succeed if the item doesn't exist (if the item doesn't exist, it's considered not equal to anything).
2. Or even simpler, use the condition `attribute_not_exists(id)`. If the item doesn't exist, the "attribute_not_exists" check will succeed, but if the item does exist, obviously its primary key exists so the attribute_not_exists condition will fail.