# dynamodb python, new items ID should increment by 1 and therefor be unique

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Creating CRUD operations on dynamo, I want item_id to be an integer and I want it to increment by 1 with every new entry to the DB, alternatively I can generate a unique integer but it has to be an integer and it has to be unique as I want it to be like the primary key, I know we don't call it that with noSQL I think it's called the partition key.

Using boto3 client will probably insert like this but where should I create the item_id, keep in mind I am using an aws lambda so would not like to rely on keeping a value in memory or anything like that.

```
client.put_item(
        TableName=ITEMS_TABLE,
        Item={
            'item_id': {'N': item_id},
            'file_name': {'S': file_name},
            'media_type': {'S': media_type},
            'created_at': {'N': created_at},
            'updated_at': {'N': updated_at},
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Giving your items a key which is a sequence number - a sequentially-growing integer - is problematic. If your application runs on multiple machines, and may created items in parallel, the application will need to safely maintain a shared counter item for the next key. Each item creation will require an additional write (with expression "counter = counter + 1" and returning the new value) to that counter, and since all writes will write to this single counter, this can become a bottleneck in a highly loaded database.

A simpler and more efficient alternative that you mentioned yourself is to give items **random** keys. However, a random key has a non-zero chance of repeating itself and generating a non-unique key. So you can create the new item with the **condition expression** that an item with that key doesn't already exist - I explained how to do this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63290492/8891224

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a conditional update (See ConditionExpression syntax). So if you want to update your counter to be 10 you need to check that the condition is 9. If it is then the update will work, if not you will get an exception and you will need to re-try.

And I think you will need to read the initial value and then do the update.
There is no one step process for this as far as I know.

Yes, it is not good to have the value in memory in the Lambda, because it is has a max limited life of 15 min. Also you might trigger more than one instance of the Lambda as it scales that will give you more than one instance with the counter in it.